# How do I generate a content hash using sha256 hash of the request body content, using the private api key with Wix Corvid

Tags: hash, base64, sha256, velo

I am seeking any information attainable in reference to creating a content hash. I am very new to the coding world and would appreciate any feedback. I have searched the Wix API Documentation and am unable to find any information pertaining to this in the forum either.

Comment: are you using Corvid (aka wix code)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install npm package into Wix. For example:

js-sha256

Then you can use this code only in backend side:

```
var sha256 = require('js-sha256');

export async function testSha256(param) {
   let p = await sha256.sha256(param);
   return p;
}
```

Then call this script from frontend, like as:

```
let hashed = await testSha256('test');
```